# Reflected attributes

Tags: lit-element

What's the **purpose** and **use** of passing an (internal) **property change** to an (external) **observed attribute**? Please, if possible, give an extrovert example.

Tia

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One primary use case is that the attribute can then be used by CSS attribute selectors. This way you can easily do conditional styling based on a state:

```css
:host([selected]) .foo {
  background-color: gray;
}

:host([mode="foo"]) .bar {

}
```

Another use case can be reflecting a property to an aria attribute, interpreted by screen readers:

```
static get properties() {
  return {
    checked: {
      type: Boolean,
      attribute: 'aria-checked',
      reflect: true,
    }
  };
}
```